# Exporting AD Query

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

Apologies, because I've seen a lot of variations on this. I've spent a ton of time lurking and looking for a solution. I'm new to Powershell and I haven't been able to get this to work. In Powershell it appears to be working, because there's just a blinking space bar after I load the module and I don't get errors (earlier versions got errors that I figured out how to stop popping up); however, when I pipe it out to CSV, there is no data.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

```
#Load Active Directory 
Import-Module activedirectory
#Load list of computers
$results = @()
$Computer = Get-Content -path 'C:\computers.txt'

#Check each computer in the list 
foreach($ComputerName in $Computer)
{
$results += Get-ADComputer -Filter { ComputerName -Like '*$ComputerName*' } -Properties name, samaccountname, lastlogondate 

 } 

#Export to CSV file
$results | export-csv 'C:\lastlogon.csv'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see 2 errors in your code
1- Filter has to be a string not a scritpblock
2- Get-ADComputer use the Name or SamAccountName properties, not computername so the correct code should be

```
$results += Get-ADComputer -Filter " Name -Like '*$ComputerName*' " -Properties name, samaccountname, lastlogondate
```

Comment: Thanks for making my first question so painless. That was exactly the problem.